# ffmpeg C++ and AVFormatContext

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a question about ffmpeg.

How I can init an `AVFormatContext` in my program. I know that it's possible to make `av_open_input_file` and use my `AVFormatContext` as one of the parametres, but my data which I want use for decoding not in file. I get it from other components of my program as char* array. Is it possible to init `AVFormatContext` struct only using this array of data.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at these functions, they might be useful.

```
AVInputFormat *av_find_input_format(const char *short_name);

AVInputFormat *av_probe_input_format(AVProbeData *pd, int is_opened);

AVInputFormat *av_probe_input_format2(AVProbeData *pd, int is_opened, int *score_max);

AVInputFormat *av_probe_input_format3(AVProbeData *pd, int is_opened, int *score_ret);

int av_probe_input_buffer(AVIOContext *pb, AVInputFormat **fmt,
                           const char *filename, void *logctx,
                           unsigned int offset, unsigned int max_probe_size);
```

I did this with output data but not input data (My input data was raw frames grabbed from a video device). what's you input data?

Comment: I get my data from socket connection as char* encoded with h.264 . And I must have an decoded video frames from it.